# Label Encoding for nominal values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I am working on dataset which has a column which is nominal i.e categorical in nature, somewhat like this:

```
>>>data['MODE'].unique()
array(['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype=object)
```

I would like to convert these nominal values to numerical counterparts(A-0,B-1,C-2). How do I do this ?

The code given is just to demonstrate the classes present in the column, I need to convert the entire column to ordinal (that is map A->0,B->1,C->2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
a = data['MODE'].unique()
print (pd.factorize(a)[0])
[0 1 2]


print (dict(zip(a, pd.factorize(a)[0])))
{'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 2}
```

Or enumerate:

```
print ({v:k for k, v in dict(enumerate(a)).items()})
{'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 2}
```

Comment: Probably should have mentioned I need to do this for the entire column

Comment: @sinha-shaurya - Then use `data['NEW'] = pd.factorize(data['MODE'])[0]`

Comment: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead , This is apparently not a very good idea(do not understand why) although it works pretty fine.

Comment: @sinha-shaurya - Is there soem filtration? like `data = data[data['col'] > 0]` before my solution? If yes, need `data = data[data['col'] > 0].copy()` for avoid warning

Comment: data=X.loc[:,(X.columns!='TYPE')&(X.columns!='ID')] I was using this. This should not be an issue right?

Comment: @sinha-shaurya - exactly, need `data=X.loc[:,(X.columns!='TYPE')&(X.columns!='ID')].copy()` If you modify values in `data` later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`X`), and that Pandas does warning.